# how can i pass data from a function to another file in react with calling that component or use props

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-props

```
filename - Header.jsx

import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { getValue } from './Input'
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';

export const Header = () => {
    const [search, setSearch] = useState('')
    useEffect(()=>{
        getValue(search,continents)
    },[search,continents])

<TextField id="outlined-basic" label="Outlined" variant="outlined" onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)} />`



filename - CountryData.jsx




let setVal = [];

export const getValue = (...val) => {
  setVal = val;
  return setVal;
};
export const CountryData = () => {
const [searchVal, setSearchVal] = useState('')
useEffect(() => {
        setSearchVal(setVal[0]);
      }, [setVal,getValue]);
}
```

i want to pass the data from input field from Header.jsx file to CountryData.jsx file without calling the component because i want to seperate the both header and CountryData element seperate in html. Maybe i am wrong in doing something. Please help and Thankyou

Comment: Using React-Redux is a good solution for sharing data between components. I would suggest you use Redux. 
Otherwise, you would have to share a common variable from the parent class and pass it as props to child components, which can be easy to achieve here but can get messy in large projects.

Comment: Does both Header.jsx and CountryData.jsx have same parent component? If not can you provide the tree of components please.

Comment: @subodhkalika thanks for help sir but can i also use create context hook instead of react-redux. I am new at react and not know much about about.

Comment: Yes, you can use context to achieve this as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [useContext](https://react.dev/reference/react/useContext#passing-data-deeply-into-the-tree). Imagine it as a store for your app. In your Header component, you can set the data/value to that store. Then, in the CountryData component, you can retrieve the data from the store to use.

Comment: thanks brother for the answer i will apply it. Are you on insta or on twitter?

Comment: No, I don't use them. But, you can contact me via Skype or email at tuanbk189@gmail.com. I'm glad that I can help.